# Non axisymmetric plate shapes

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to obtain the next figures:

[image]

[image]

They must keep some boundary conditions in the outside edge (zero slope, zero displacement), so the function in polar coordinates is:

[image]

The above figures correspond to m=1,2. I am trying with this code in TiKz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{20},unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
\addplot3[mesh,color=black,surf, colormap/cool,
samples=30,trig format=rad,
domain=-1:1, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({x*cos(2*y)},
{x*sin(2*y)},{((1-(x^2))^2)*(cos(2*y))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I get only:

[image]

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: I didn't know how to accept the answers. Now I did it. Thank you so much for the help in all questions. I tried  already changing the domain and the unit vector ratio, any of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly my first approximation didn't work. Finally I could finished it (without the blue lines), here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={30}{30},unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
\addplot3[surf, mesh/interior colormap= {white}{color=(white) color=(white)},
line width=0.5pt,faceted color=black,
samples=31,trig format=rad,
domain=0:1.176, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({(x)*cos(y)},
{(x)*sin(y)},{(0.5*sin(y)*cos(2*(x+0.804)*pi)/(1+(x+0.804)^2))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces:

[image]

and the other figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-20}{30},unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
\addplot3[surf, mesh/interior colormap= {white}{color=(white) color=(white)},
line width=0.5pt,faceted color=black,
samples=31,trig format=rad,
domain=0:1.176, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({(1*x)*cos(y)},
{(1*x)*sin(y)},{(0.5*sin(2*y)*cos(2*(x+0.804)*pi)/(1+(x+0.804)^2))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not an answer since I am unable to recreate the discs with the function you specify. However, what this answer does is to show you how to draw the blue curves once you have found the function or the bug in my code. To this end, it helps to make the function known to Ti*k*Z using `declare function` and use it whenever needed. In `f(\x,\y,\z)` `\x`, `\y` and `\z` take the roles of `r`, `\theta` and `m` in you formula. The curves can simply be added by using a 3d parametric plot. Note, however, that pgfplots won't hide them (without additional effort) if the curves are behind the surface.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y,\z)=((1-\x*\x)*(1-\x*\x))*cos(\z*\y);}]
\begin{axis}[view={60}{20},unit vector ratio=1 1 0.6]
\addplot3[mesh,color=black,%surf, colormap/cool,
samples=31,trig format=rad,
domain=0:1, y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({x*cos(y)},
{x*sin(y)},{f(x,y,1)});
\addplot3[mesh,color=blue,thick,%surf, colormap/cool,
samples=31,samples y=1,trig format=rad,
domain=-1:1, 
z buffer=sort]
({x*cos(0)},
{x*sin(0)},{f(x,0,1))});
\addplot3[mesh,color=blue,thick,%surf, colormap/cool,
samples=31,samples y=1,trig format=rad,
domain=-1:1, 
z buffer=sort]
({x*cos(pi/2)},
{x*sin(pi/2)},{f(x,pi/2,1)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the output is not very similar to what you want. However, IMHO opinion this is not pgfplot's fault. Rather for small `r` the function is close to 1 times the cosine, which assumes values between `-1` and `+1` and thus explains the crazy shape close to the origin.